# Aligning Date Indices in Time Series to Create a Supervised Regression Dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I would like to convert a time series dataset into a supervised regression dataset using the provided code. In the resulting dataset, I expect the date indices to represent the dates for the values to be predicted (based on the last code before Multi-Step or Sequence Forecasting, which is presented [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/convert-time-series-supervised-learning-problem-python/)). However, the code currently uses the dates from the input data as the relevant indices.

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Optional, Tuple, Union, List
FORECAST_HORIZON = 1
target_variable = 'Sales'
TARGET_VARIABLE = target_variable
AR_FROM_Y = True  # Autoregressive features from y
AR_FROM_WEATHER_DATA = False  #
LAGS = 2
MAX_LAGS = 2
def create_future_features(
        df: pd.DataFrame,
        target_variables: list[str],
        fhs: Union[int, list[int]] = FORECAST_HORIZON,
    ) -> pd.DataFrame:
       
        # If fh is an int, convert it to a list of ints
        if isinstance(fhs, int):
            fhs = [fhs] * len(target_variables)
        # If fh is a list, ensure that it has the same length as target_variables
        elif isinstance(fhs, list) and len(fhs) != len(target_variables):
            raise ValueError(
                "If fh is a list, it must have the same length as target_variables"
            )

        # # Create future features
        future_columns = {}
        for target_variable, fh in zip(target_variables, fhs):
            for i in range(1, fh + 1):
                future_columns[f"{target_variable}_fh_{i}"] = df[
                    target_variable
                ].shift(-i)

        future_df = pd.DataFrame(future_columns)
        
        return future_df

def create_ar_features(
        series: pd.Series, lags: int, use_pacf: bool = False, max_lags: int = 3
    ) -> pd.DataFrame:

        best_lag = lags
        ar_features = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                f"{series.name}_lag_{i}": series.shift(i)
                for i in range(best_lag)
            }
        )
        ar_features.index = series.index

        # Drop the newly created NaNs at the beginning, but retain existing NaNs in the original series
        ar_features = ar_features.iloc[best_lag - 1 :]
        
        return ar_features
def _align_timestamps(
        *dfs: Optional[Union[pd.DataFrame, pd.Series]], use_union: bool = False
    ) -> Union[
        Optional[Union[pd.DataFrame, pd.Series]],
        Tuple[Optional[Union[pd.DataFrame, pd.Series]]],
    ]:
        
        # Check if any of the inputs are None and handle them appropriately
        non_none_dfs = [df for df in dfs if df is not None]
        if not non_none_dfs:
            raise ValueError(
                "At least one DataFrame or Series must be provided."
            )

        # Find common index across all non-None DataFrames or Series
        common_index = non_none_dfs[0].index
        for df in non_none_dfs[1:]:
            if use_union:
                common_index = common_index.union(df.index)
            else:
                common_index = common_index.intersection(df.index)

        # Reindex and let NaNs propagate forward
        output_dfs = [
            df.reindex(common_index) if df is not None else None for df in dfs
        ]

        if len(output_dfs) == 1:
            return output_dfs[0]
        else:
            return tuple(output_dfs)
def create_features(
        df: pd.DataFrame,
        target_variable: str = TARGET_VARIABLE,
        ar_from_y: bool = AR_FROM_Y,
        ar_from_weather_data: bool = AR_FROM_WEATHER_DATA,
        lags: int = LAGS,
        max_lags: int = MAX_LAGS,
        use_pacf: bool = False,
        drop_na: bool = True,
    ) -> pd.DataFrame:
   
        # Don't modify the original DataFrame
        df = df.copy()

        y = df[target_variable]
        weather_data = df.drop(columns=target_variable)

      
        # If autoregressive features from y are requested, add them
        if ar_from_y:
            y_ar_features = create_ar_features(
                y, lags, use_pacf, max_lags
            )
            df, y_ar_features = _align_timestamps(df, y_ar_features)  # type: ignore
            df = pd.merge(
                df,  # type: ignore
                y_ar_features,  # type: ignore
                left_index=True,
                right_index=True,
                how="inner",
            )

    
        # Drop NaNs
        if drop_na:
            df.dropna(inplace=True)

        return df
def df_to_X_y(
        df: pd.DataFrame,
        target_variable: str = TARGET_VARIABLE,
        fh: int = FORECAST_HORIZON,
        dropna: bool = True,
    ) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]:
     
        # Create features
        df = create_features(df, target_variable)
        # Create X
        X = df.drop(columns=target_variable)
        # Ensure that X is a DataFrame
        if isinstance(X, pd.Series):
            X = X.to_frame()

        # Create y
        y = create_future_features(df, [target_variable], fh)

        if dropna:
            # Drop rows with NaNs
            y = y.dropna()
            X = X.loc[y.index]

        return X, y
```

The output generated by the code for this basic dataset is shown below.

```
# Generate a list of dates from 1991-01-01 to 2023-03-01
date_range = pd.date_range(start="2000-01-01", end="2001-03-01", freq="MS")

# Create random values for column target
num_rows = len(date_range)
values_Sales = range(0,num_rows)

# Create a dictionary with column names and corresponding values
data = {
    "Sales": values_Sales,
}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=date_range)
X, y = df_to_X_y(df, target_variable)
print(X)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
          Sales_lag_0  Sales_lag_1
2000-02-01            1          0.0
2000-03-01            2          1.0
2000-04-01            3          2.0
2000-05-01            4          3.0
           Sales_fh_1
2000-02-01         2.0
2000-03-01         3.0
2000-04-01         4.0
2000-05-01         5.0
```

However, the desired output format should resemble the following:

```
          Sales_lag_0  Sales_lag_1
2000-03-01            1          0.0
2000-04-01            2          1.0
2000-05-01            3          2.0
2000-06-01            4          3.0
           Sales_fh_1
2000-03-01         2.0
2000-04-01         3.0
2000-05-01         4.0
2000-06-01         5.0
```